# What configuration should be modified as the below error logs after I had modified CN name by Default in API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

[image]

firstly ,I had modified CN name by default and I tried to regenerate an Access Token,but it prompted the http error code 500. 
the screenshot is the error log.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1) Use the same hostname for CN of certificate and the hostname of the URL. (This is the ideal way to do this)

2) Disable hostname verification in Synapse [like this](https://cnapagoda.blogspot.com/2014/08/host-name-verification-failed-for.html).

Comment: I do it as your second option and It also does not work. I modified the configuration of axis2.xml in the directory repository/conf/axis2/. 
The detail likes this.<parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            </TrustStore></parameter>
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter

Comment: when your team use the AM and config some APIs in AM, then how you can invoke API by "HttpClient"?

Comment: I use httpclient to invoke the API and the error logs is the following:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <14.21.6.24> != <localhost>

Comment: I think I already told you this in a previous question. CN and hostname of URL should be the same.